# Pesquisa que mostra o conteúdo de uma div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando criar um site que vai me ajudar aqui no trabalho, que é o seguinte:

Queria que aparecesse na página inicial somente uma caixa de pesquisa, nada mais. Todo conteúdo necessário só iria aparecer conforme eu pesquisasse.

Ex: Ao pesquisar por "receita de pão cru" apareceria minha div com o título e a receita completa, que eu já teria escrito.

Principais perguntas:
Poderiam ao menos iluminar meu caminho para eu prosseguir? 
Tem como eu fazer isso sem precisar mexer com SQL? (Não entendo nada de SQL)
Há uma forma de eu criar um monte de DIV e esconde-las, aparecendo-as somente ao serem pesquisadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer isso com Jquery:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Pesquisar</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.contact-name').hide();
   $('#search').click(function(){
    $('.contact-name').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.contact-name').each(function(){
       if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1){
        $(this).show();
       }
    });
   });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="search-criteria"/>
  <input type="button" id="search" value="Pesquisar"/>
  <div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">João da Silva</a></h3></div>
  <div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Lucas Santos</a></h3></div>
  <div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Matheus Gonçalves</a></h3></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PQPPPPP QUE FODA!!! ERA EXATAMENTE ISSO QUE EU QUERIAA!!!!! MUITO OBRIGADO

Answer (score 0):

Tente o código abaixo: digite doce, ou bolo, etc.

```js
 $(function(){
   var data = {
    "receita":
       [
           {
               "nome":"Doce de Leite Ninho",
               "ingredientes":"200 g de biscoito de maisena.<br>4 colheres (sopa) de manteiga derretida.<br>2 caixas de creme de leite.<br>1 xícara de leite ninho.<br>24 g de <br>elatina incolor sem sabor.<br>200 g de creme de avelã<br>leite em pó a gosto para finalizar.",
           },
           {
            "nome":"Bolo de Batata Doce",
               "ingredientes":"3 ovos.<br>1 xícara (chá) de manteiga da terra (manteiga de garrafa)<br>2 xícaras (chá) de açúcar.<br>3 xícaras (chá) de farinha de trigo.<br>3 <br>ícaras (chá) de leite.<br>1 xícara (chá) de coco ralado.<br>1 xícara (chá) de leite de coco.<br>1,5 kg de batata-doce cozida e espremida.",
           },
       ]}

       $("button").click(function(){
        $("#resultado").empty();
        $.each(data.receita, function(i,v){ 
         var txt = v.nome.toLowerCase();
         var n = txt.indexOf( $("#dsPesquisa").val().toLowerCase() );
         if( ( n >= 0 ) && ( $("#dsPesquisa").val().length >= 3 ) )
          $("#resultado").append('<h4>' + v.nome + '</h4>' + '<p>' + v.ingredientes + '</p>')
        })
        return false;
       })
       
 })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="mb-3">Pesquisa de Receitas</h3>
      <form name="pesquisa" id="pesquisa">
       <input type="text" name="dsPesquisa" id="dsPesquisa">
       <button>Ok</button>
      </form>
      <div id="resultado" class="mt-3"></div>
     </div> 
    </div>    
 </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```